Encoding error repeatedly appears in Xamarin
I am trying to make a Xamarin application but constantly run into this error without even knowing what is causing it. It reappears from time to time, and the only solution I have found so far is to delete the local repository and clone it again. This sometimes causes data loss.
I tried changing the encoding method in a few files, but that didn't help.
Unexpected error in XamlCTask task.
System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the specified encoding. Line 9, position 90.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32& charsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32 maxCharsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributeValueSlow(Int32 curPos, Char quoteChar, NodeData attr)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseXamlElementFor(IElementNode node, XmlReader reader) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\XamlParser.cs:Line 61.
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlParser.ReadNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean nested) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\XamlParser.cs:Line 174.
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseXamlElementFor(IElementNode node, XmlReader reader) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\XamlParser.cs:Line 114.
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlParser.ReadNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean nested) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\XamlParser.cs:Line 174.
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseXamlElementFor(IElementNode node, XmlReader reader) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\XamlParser.cs:Line 114.
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseXaml(RootNode rootNode, XmlReader reader) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\XamlParser.cs:Line 49.
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Build.Tasks.XamlTask.ParseXaml(Stream stream, TypeReference typeReference) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Build.Tasks\XamlTask.cs:Line 59.
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute(IList`1& thrownExceptions) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Build.Tasks\XamlCTask.cs:Line 124.
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Build.Tasks.XamlTask.Execute() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Build.Tasks\XamlTask.cs:Line 38.
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()


Are you authoring XAML/XML files? Try to use an Unicode encoding like UTF-8, not an 8 bit code page or encoding like ISO-8859-1 or Windows 1252. But it is only a guess as to why you get an error like "Invalid character in the specified encoding". And if those files are generated and not authored you will need to wait for someone familiar with Xamarin/MAUI to tell where the encoding problem might be caused.

What is the invalid character?  It may be the code that generated the xml did not properly encode the character or it could be bit errors are occurring when the xml is be transmitted.  You need to find out if this is due to a random error or it is always the same character that is causing the issue.
